# Nested class of an array, want to grab index of outer array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I have 2 classes, the creature class will have the nodes array as a property. But the creatures will also be held in an array. I want to be able to grab the creatures index from any of the nodes. Currently all I have been able to do is be able to grab the creatures index from the creature itself. I've been trying to look into using a set function inside the creature class, to set the creature index number of the creature as well as set all the nodes' creature index number as the same number.

```js
//Node class
class Node {
    constructor(x, y, r, color, highlight, highlightColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r || 20;
        this.color = color || "#ff0";
        this.highlight = highlight || false;
        this.highlightColor = highlightColor || "#0000FF";
    }
}

// Creature class
class Creature {
    constructor(nodes, muscles, nodeColors) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
        this.muscles = muscles;
        this.nodeColors = nodeColors || "#ff0";

        Object.defineProperties(this, {

            nodesArray: {
                "get": (i) => this.nodes[i],
                "set": nodes => {
                    this.nodes[i] = newNode;
                }
            },

            musclesArray: {
                "get": (i) => this.nodes[i],
                "set": muscles => {
                    this.muscles[i] = newMuscle;
                }
            },
            creatureNumber: {
                "get": () => creatures.indexOf(this),
            }
        });
    }
}

var nodes = [
    new Node(100, 100),
    new Node(200, 200)
];

var creatures = [
    new Creature(nodes, muscles)
];
```

Comment: I've read your question a couple of times and I am not sure what you want tp achieve. Can you perhaps add a small example array and based on that explain what it is you need to get?

Comment: For solving your issue AND better performance at the same time, maybe you should consider storing explicitly the id in Creature objects (because "array.indexOf" is not very efficient, O(N)).

Comment: @Thijs the arrays are in the snippet. Basically I'll have these two arrays. Each will extend their respective classes. And each creature will hold an array of nodes. What I want to do is to be able to take only one of those nodes, and be able to grab the index of the creature in the array of other creatures. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Joel But even if I had that, how would I be able to grab that id from only one node? I'm using array.indexOf because the creatures array will constantly change. Do you have another method of grabbing the index as it updates?

Comment: If you have the id not as the array index, but an incremental number that never changes for a given creature... and use an object/map [number=>Creature] instead of the array. But I missed the point about the "nodes" nested objects, what about storing its parent (creature) reference directly in node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your class a bit (not even sure yours work as you think they do) and added an extra class to manage the creatures. I don't think your setup with the array is going to work.

```js
//Node class
class Node {
    constructor(x, y, r, color, highlight, highlightColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r || 20;
        this.color = color || "#ff0";
        this.highlight = highlight || false;
        this.highlightColor = highlightColor || "#0000FF";
    }

  /* === PROPERTY: parentCreature === */
  get parentCreature() {
    return this._parentCreature;
  }
  set parentCreature(creature) {
    this._parentCreature = creature;
  }
  
  
  /* === METHODS: removeFromCreature === */
  removeFromCreature() {
    this._parentCreature = null;
  }

}

function setParentForNodes() {
  this.nodesArray.forEach(node => {
    node.parentCreature = this;
  });
}

// Creature class
class Creature {
    /* === CONSTRUCTOR === */
    constructor(nodes, muscles, nodeColors) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
        this.muscles = muscles;
        this.nodeColors = nodeColors || "#ff0";
        
        setParentForNodes.call(this);
    }


    /* === PROPERTY: nodesArray === */
    get nodesArray() {
      return this.nodes;
    }
    set nodesArray(value) {
      this.nodes = value;
      setParentForNodes.call(this);
    }
    
    /* === PROPERTY: musclesArray === */
    get musclesArray() {
      return this.musclesArray;
    }
    set musclesArray(value) {
      this.musclesArray = value;
    }
    
    
    /* === METHODS: removeNodes === */
    removeNodes() {
      this.nodes.forEach(node => {
        node.parentCreature = null;
      });
      this.nodes = null;
    }
}



class Creatures {
  /* === CONSTRUCTOR === */
  constructor(creaturesArray = []) {
    this.creatures = new Map();
    
    creaturesArray.forEach(creature => {
      this.creatures.set(creature.id, creature.model);
    });
  }
  
  /* === METHOD: addCreature === */
  addCreature(id, model) {
    if (this.creatures.has(id)) {
      console.log('Creature ID already exists');
      return;
    }
    
    this.creatures.set(id, model);
  }

  /* === METHOD: getCreatureById === */
  getCreatureById(id) {
    if (this.creatures.has(id)) {
      return this.creatures.get(id);
    }
    
    return null;
  }
}

// Create the nodes
var nodes = [
    new Node(100, 100),
    new Node(200, 200)
];

// Create the Goblin with the nodes.
var creatures = new Creatures([
    {
      id: 'goblin',
      model: new Creature(nodes, 'muscles')
    }
]);


// Create the dwarf, it has no nodes
creatures.addCreature('dwarf', new Creature([], 'muscles'));


const
  // Get the parent creature for the first node.
  parentCreatureForNode = nodes[0].parentCreature,
  // Get the creature instance for the dwarf.
  dwarf = creatures.getCreatureById('dwarf');
  
// Remove the nodes from the parent of the first node.
parentCreatureForNode.removeNodes();
// Assign the nodes to the dwarf.
dwarf.nodesArray = nodes;

// The goblin should report it has no nodes.
console.log(creatures.getCreatureById('goblin'));
// The dwarf should log it has 2 nodes.
console.log(creatures.getCreatureById('dwarf'));
// Make sure the node reports its parent is the dwarf.
console.log(nodes[0].parentCreature === dwarf);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I think I will be using some of this code for later. But looking through, I still think I'll run into the same problem if I used this. Because I'm trying to basically attach 2 nodes together but once they attach, they will be both under the same creature ID. So I'm thinking each node will have to be able to hold the property of what creature they are a part of. So that when I call it, I can just delete 1 creature and add all the nodes and muscles from that creature into the other.

Comment: I've changed the answer... I think it now does what you want it to.

Comment: Worked great, I actually only needed to take that setParentForNodes function, but I'll still be taking some of your other suggestions to clean up my code, thanks a lot!